# Select2 jQuery restrict user to add tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

My HTML Code

```
<select class="select2_tag_example" multiple>
</select>
```

I have include jquery and css that required for select2 and add initialization jQuery as under

```
$(".select2_tag_example").select2({
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
    allowClear: true,
});
```

My select is converted to select2 successfully, but problem is that I want to restrict some tags(strings) that dose not allow to enter in multi select2 box like "rock".

How can I restrict user to does not allow enter some of words(tags).

advise accepted,

Thanks in advance.